# jQuery - Format Minutes and Seconds - 00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I have a text input field that accepts a time in minutes and seconds, in the following format:

```
00:00
```

Now, if a user types something like this:

```
00:61
```

I would need it to be formatted (on "blur") to:

```
01:01
```

I have taken a look at plugin like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), but they all do not seem to be able to do this kind of time formatting.

Does anybody know of a way in jQuery or JavaScript to accomplish this?

Comment: Yeah... you divide by 60 and add # digits it's divisible by. Better use jQuery for that math.

Comment: It would help if you supplied your code for us to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) method on `blur` event to achieve this. Here is an example;

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('blur', 'input', function(e) {
        $(this).val(function(i, val) {
            var timeParts = val.split(':'),
                totalSeconds = parseInt(timeParts[0], 10) * 60 + parseInt(timeParts[1], 10),
                minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60),
                seconds = totalSeconds - (minutes * 60);
         return [minutes < 10 ? 0 : '', minutes, ':', seconds < 10 ? 0 : '', seconds].join('');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="00:61">
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/BoRXgq

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  var values = '';
  input.value.split(':').reduce(function(a,b) {
    a = ~~a;
    b= ~~b;
    if (b >= 60) {
      a += ~~(b / 60);
      b = b % 60;
    }
    values += a +':'+ b;
    return b;
  });

  input.value = values;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may not be exactly what You want, but maybe it is better to use something like [bootstrap timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)?